# Share virtually screen without disconnected

Tags: windows, multiple-instances, ultravnc

Hi guys I need advise there. Hoping can get answer from here.
What is good method to share screen only view mode?
So users can virtually see what happen on that computer, but only view.
I tried this with Ultra VNC, I'm the admin. It works but if I disconnected from the computer users also lost their view. But I want them still able virtually view the process on that computer.

Answer (score 0):

Teamviewer could do this. Before the other connect, you need to edit your teamviewer settings to not enable any action from guest, after it if the guest join he will be only able to watch what going on but no more.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try [ABTutor](http://www.abtutor.com/) it has a very good viewer function.  I use it even to administrate my workstations on my network.  It is not free though, but worth every sent.